# Fill the destination email field using MAPISendMail

Tags: c++, mapi

I'm implementing a "Print and Email" function in my application, and I launch the default email client using [MAPISendMail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296721(v=vs.85).aspx), with a file attachment pre-selected. I want to be able to automatically fill the "To" field, as well, but I couldn't find an option for that in the [MapiMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296732(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. There are options for subject, body, attachments, but not for the "To" field.

Is there any way to fill the "To" field using [MAPISendMail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296721(v=vs.85).aspx)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, there is a recipient field in the MapiMessage structure. Here some sample code I found at http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Microsoft_Development/A_1820-Sending-Email-with-MAPI.html that illustrates how to fill the recipient field:

```
BOOL SendMail(LPCSTR lpszSubject, LPCSTR lpszTo, 
    LPCSTR lpszName, LPCSTR lpszText)
{
    HINSTANCE hMAPI = ::LoadLibrary(L"mapi32.dll");
    LPMAPISENDMAIL lpfnMAPISendMail = 
        (LPMAPISENDMAIL)::GetProcAddress(hMAPI, "MAPISendMail");

    char szTo[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    strcat_s(szTo, lpszTo);

    char szName[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    strcat_s(szName, lpszName);

    MapiRecipDesc recipient[1] = { 0 };
    recipient[0].ulRecipClass = MAPI_TO;
    recipient[0].lpszAddress = szTo;
    recipient[0].lpszName = szName;

    char szSubject[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    strcat_s(szSubject, lpszSubject);

    char szText[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    strcat_s(szText, lpszText);

    MapiMessage MAPImsg = { 0 };
    MAPImsg.lpszSubject = szSubject;
    MAPImsg.lpRecips = recipient;
    MAPImsg.nRecipCount = 1;
    MAPImsg.lpszNoteText = szText;

    ULONG nSent = lpfnMAPISendMail(0, 0, 
        &MAPImsg, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_DIALOG, 0);

    FreeLibrary(hMAPI);
    return (nSent == SUCCESS_SUCCESS || nSent == MAPI_E_USER_ABORT);
}
```